# Two DbContexts using same models, error while saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get data from dbContext and save it to other dbContext.
Actually, I want to import some data base on some validation from database A and store it to database B. I know there are other ways to do that but I want to it using EF with two DBContexts.

Here is the scenario:
I've to DbContext class with names: `T1Entities`, `InterfaceDbContext`

these dbContext are using the same Models.
Like I've a class with name `orders` and I'm using the same class for other of these context.

Like this way:

```
public partial class T1Entities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class InterfaceDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and in my `GetOrder` function, I'm trying to get only those orders that are not present in InterfaceDbContext and trying to insert on that context.

```
public List<orders_mstr> GetOrders()
{
    // getting interface db Orders
    var interfaceOrders = _interfaceDb.Orders.ToList();

    // getting T1 db orders which are not present in it interface db
    var orders = _t1Db.Orders
                    .Where(o =>
                                interfaceOrders.All(x => x.id != o.id)
                    )
                    .ToList();


    // trying to save the first object.
    _interfaceDb.Orders.Add(orders[0]);
    _interfaceDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm having exception here while saving:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

**Please note:** I've to use the save Order class for other of the contexts. I know we can do that by creating different other class for each of these contexts.

Comment: Don't you need to detach the entities from the first context before adding them to the second?

Comment: I'm not sure. how we can do that?

Comment: Turn off proxy creation of the source context before retrieving the data, e.g. `_t1Db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; var orders = _t1Db.Orders....`

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I detach objects in Entity Framework Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599147/how-do-i-detach-objects-in-entity-framework-code-first)

```
var orders = _t1Db.Orders
    .AsNoTracking() // Query without tracking
    .Where(o =>
                interfaceOrders.All(x => x.id != o.id)
    )
    .ToList();
```